# Unlocking screen brings up Phone app on Lollipop

Tags: lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop, phone-app

I just updated my Nexus 4 to Lollipop. Now, every time I unlock my phone, the Phone app opens. Surely this is a bug and not a feature. It doesn't matter if I received a notification; and I'm not clicking the phone icon at the bottom - I slide to unlock, draw my secret pattern and am instantly taken to the phone app.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Swiping to the right opens the phone, swiping to the left, the camera and swiping up unlocks to the home screen.

Comment: This seems to be a common complaint.