# Set screen when unlock device

Tags: lock-screens, samsung

I've purchased S6 and when unlock the there is a phone screen on by default instead of home screen. How to set the default screen to "home" after unlocking device ?

Related : [Unlocking screen brings up Phone app on Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/unlocking-screen-brings-up-phone-app-on-lollipop)

Update :
I used default lock screen and swiping to right to unlock caused issue

Comment: I assume your Galaxy S6 is running on Lollipop, then you have to swipe-up just like the link mentions. As of currently written, it is unclear: how do you swipe when unlocking the device? Swipe to the right, up, or left?

Comment: @Andrew t. I now unlock using fingerprint which resolves the issue

Comment: That's great! But before that, let's make this question clearer first. Before you changed to fingerprint, what lock screen did you use, and what did you do when unlocking the device that made this issue happen?

Comment: @Andrew t. Please see question update

Comment: By looking at the [lock screen on S6](http://fs01.androidpit.info/userfiles/4774964/image/AndroidPIT-Galaxy-S6-Android-5-0-2-Lollipop-TouchWiz-lock-screen-home-screen.jpg), I believe this question is indeed a dupe of the question you linked.